# Are there any open/delete/copy file events that can be caught before the action starts?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, c#-4.0

How can I find out that user tries to open a file?
I found some events in Windows API but they just notice that file was opened.

Answer (score 0):

Using `FileSystemWatcher` you can track various changes on the file, see the filters `NotifyFilters`-

- http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/246319-FileSystemWatcher-for-opening-files
- [FileSystemWatcher triggers for filestream open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226892/filesystemwatcher-triggers-for-filestream-open)

Comment: That only triggers it's events after the action has happened however, not before.

Comment: What is the reason for knowing when user tries to open (even before file open action). what are you trying to do, please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe he's working on future prediction technology, and hoping to have code reuse? :)

Comment: i'm trying to make an aplication that permits/allows  user to send an file throw email, tries to open it. maybe later it coud be an data loss prevention system on the endpoints. an example: you have an troyan on your computer and it has the same rights as loged user and it is sendig out file after file. i need to catch that proces tries to manipulate with the file. what proces what file and than i can deside whether i allow or disallow that action.

Comment: You can set the NotifyFilter-property to LastAccess, and catch the Changed-event and you can control whatever you want in this block. The LastAccess timestamp would be changed the moment file is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below link to know how can your create and use FileSystemWatcher component to monitor the changes made to the file system.

http://www.mstecharticles.com/2012/09/c-monitor-file-system-using.html