# C# WPF: Loading data from dynamically generated image files

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, dynamic-data

I am wondering how I can load information from dynamically generated files?

For example:
There will be 20 images generated every 10 seconds; Image files are going to be save under `D:\ drive`, something like:

```
D:\image1.tif is generated at 1s, 
D:\image2.tif is generated at 11s and
D:\image3.tif is generated at 21s,
```

and so on so forth.

Then once a new image is generated, I want to load some information, a pixel intensity for instance, from the image immediately. But I want to do that after the generation of the image is complete.

Then I am going to display the information I just retrieved to my WPF form.

So what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filesystem changes can be monitored using [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). Of course, you can implement some simpler filesystem change detection mechanism by polling (retrieving the listing) the certain filesystem directory by yourself.

So, when a filesystem change is detected, load the info about the file and display it.

Update:

Yes, to detect whether file modification is completed (periodically trying to open the file), please take a look at the question: [FileSystemWatcher triggers for filestream open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226892/filesystemwatcher-triggers-for-filestream-open).

Comment: Does that guarantee that the notification will be sent after the file is completely saved? Because I was told the system will send the signal as long as file changes occur, but regardless whether the change is completed. That is what I am concerning.

Comment: @NickTsui, yes, you're right: there should be an additional logic to check whether modification is completed (periodically trying to open the file). Please see the updated answer.